# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null in Angular2?

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I am getting this exception while calling http request for mock.json

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at PromiseCompleter.reject (zone.js:515)
    at eval (core.umd.js:8981)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (core.umd.js:6075)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
    at zone.js:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6066)
```

Comment: Probably one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165992/angular-2-exception-typeerror-cannot-read-property-isskipself-of-null-brow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612802/error-cannot-read-property-isskipself-of-null-after-upgraded-from-abgular-be, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402620/dont-know-how-to-implement-an-enum-using-an-interface-in-an-angular-class

Comment: Thanks @ GünterZöchbauer I followed ur link : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8519  but i havent used @ Pipes. still getting issue

Comment: @SarveshYadav can u share ur code ?

Comment: @candidJ Sure !! you can see mine code here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613097/no-provider-for-response-in-angular-2-even-thought-i-have-added-providers-in-com i also made some changges this.carService.getCarsMedium().subscribe((cars: SelectItem[]) => this.cars = cars);

Comment: @SarveshYadav theirry provided a plunker link of your code. was that helpful ? and did you try using `map` operator instead of `toPromise`?